# Connect PC to TV via home network

Tags: smart-tv

I am setting up the cables for my under-construction home. I couldn't find ways to connect a PC to the TV with both of them plugged into the same network switch.

I don't want to run display port cables, I know it works with Wi-Fi and that would be ok but is there a way to say, stream a movie to the TV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few different options, though I'm sure there are others and I'm curious to hear about them:

1. Buy a Chromecast, hook it up to the TV, and use VLC on the PC in order to cast media to it. If you need to cast the desktop to it, there is at least [one](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/04/how-to-cast-your-gnome-shell-desktop-to.html) GNOME project that seems to support it (though how well it works, I do not know). This is still wireless though.
2. If media streaming is the main concern, you could purchase a cheap Android TV or Plex box or Kodi box or other product that connects to the wired network to read network media (that would, presumably, live on your existing PC), and transcodes/streams it to the TV via an HDMI port. These typically have friendly UIs for browsing network drives. Though in this case, you're not really "streaming from your PC" so much as "pulling from the PC."
3. If full, arbitrary desktop screen casting is required and it needs to be wired, then I'm not familiar with any "HDMI/DP-to-ethernet" and "ethernet-to-HDMI/DP" adapters. They might exist, but I imagine they'd be very expensive, and the ethernet would just be used as a Layer 1 medium to run the underlying HDMI/DP signal further than the HDMI/DP specs allow; the adapters wouldn't act like fully-capable Layer 3 routable nodes on the network. That is, you couldn't just buy an "HDMI/DP-to-ethernet" adapter, plug your PC into the HDMI/DP side, and plug the ethernet into your switch, and then have the signal make its way to your TV, which is also connected over ethernet (the TV would be playing the role of the "ethernet-to-HDMI/DP" role in that case; I'm not aware of any TV that can do that (and the HDMI/DP-to-ethernet adapter would need to be Layer 3-aware, which I suspect doesn't exist even if the adapter does)). You'd have to have a dedicated ethernet run from the PC to the TV, with adapters on both ends. The network switch wouldn't help you here.

In each above case though, the TV is eventually receiving an HDMI or DP signal. If the constraint is that the TV should only receive the relevant data over ethernet, then the only option I'm aware of would be applications on the TV itself that could read media off your PC over the network.

Comment: My build came with MiraCast fuctionality out-of-box (Maximus X Hero Wifi-AC board).  However, the Intel driver dropped MiraCast support and I had to switch to a Realtek driver to keep the function.

Comment: Thanks, I did find that some TVs have software you install on the PC to connect to them but not as a general solution and thus I wasn't finding it. I realize it would also be wrong if Windows can just connect to your TV because then someone else can do it too.